# Is the SQL Server Express memory and CPU limit per instance?

Tags: sql-server, memory, sql-server-express, instance

If I have 8GB of RAM in a server and I run 4 instances of SQL Server Express, will the total memory limit used by SQL Server be 1GB or 4GB?

Would it be advisable to run multiple instances like this to enable each database to make better use of resources (assuming that the server has plenty of resources)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> If I have 8GB of RAM in a server and I run 4 instances of SQL Express,
>   will the total memory limit used by SQL Server be 1GB or 4GB?

[Each instance can use up to 1GB of memory for the buffer pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#CrossBoxScale).  Each instance can use a bit more than 1GB in total because not all memory allocations go via the buffer pool.  In your case, the maximum memory used by the four instances for buffer pool would be 4GB.

[image: BOL extract]

To confirm, I started two *instances* of the SQL Server 2008 Express Database Engine, performed some activity to load up the (separate) buffer pools, and then looked at per-instance memory utilization in a number of ways, for example using [DBCC MEMORYSTATUS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271624) or by counting the number of buffers using the [sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173442.aspx) DMV.

The *physical memory usage* numbers below were obtained using simultaneous queries against the system DMV [sys.dm_os_process_memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510747.aspx) on each instance of the database engine:

```
SELECT 
    dopm.physical_memory_in_use_kb 
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory AS dopm;
```

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ Instance1 ║ Instance2 ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╣
║   1102872 ║   1059812 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Each of these is slightly in excess of 1GB as total physical memory usage includes more than just buffer pool usage, as mentioned previously.

> Would it be advisable to run multiple instances like this to enable
>   each database to make better use of resources (assuming that the
>   server has plenty of resources)?

If the databases on each instance are functionally independent then it is at least workable to run multiple instances of Express in this way, though you would need to pay careful attention to configuration and maintenance may be made more complex.

You might be be better served using another edition, such as the fully-featured (and very cheap) Developer Edition, if the intended usage matches the licence).  You would need to say much more about the circumstances to get a clear answer on this point.

Comment: Also of note, for the astute reader: `SQL Server Database Engine` means `A Single Instance`. Everytime you have to change the connection dialog server that you're connecting to (eg `localhost\dev` vs `localhost\test`) that's a new "Instance" or a new "Engine". Just thought I would clear that up.

Answer (score 7):

Every Instance counts separate as it has a separate process.

Comment: I assume that you are certain that the limiter isn't applied across all processes then?

Answer (score -8):

In SQL Express, **the database engine can only consume 1 GB RAM**, and any DB cannot be larger than 10 GB.

So, 4 instances would still have to share that 1 GB RAM.

You can find out much more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx.

A similar discussion here on Stack Overflow says this is the right answer BTW, so no need to downvote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169634/limitations-of-sql-server-express

This page says the same, even though it is about SQL Server Express 2005: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-server-2000-2003/55183-sql-server-express-2005-memory-limit-per-instance.html

Comment: Doesn't necessarily follow - is it 1 engine per server or per instance?

Comment: 1 engine per server.

Comment: Not following either. This seems somewhat ambiguous. The document says 1 GB per database engine. I believe each service/instance would count as a separate engine, so they'd each get 1 GB. Roy, do you have any other references on this?

Comment: I've had 2 conflicting answers so far - does anyone have anything unambiguous and authoritative to quote or can at least say that they have actually tried it?

Comment: On that page, the Maximum Compute Capacity is expressed per instance, whereas the memory capacity does *not* explicitly mention per instance.

Comment: OK, that does imply it, but it is also possible that they missed it out on the memory limit line.

Comment: Anything is possible. Either way, I've added extra references. Will those who downvoted be honest enough to undo that please.

Comment: Just because it's on the internet, it has to be true. They would never let something wrong be on the internet. ~ Saying that to say that the issue here is that there has to be a management process or something baked into the OS for the sole purpose of restricting all SQL Express forever. I really don't think that has happened (AKA it absolutely didn't happen, based on the fact that I breathe oxygen and can follow logic really well) so the fact of the matter is that the process itself manages the amount of RAM being used.

Comment: Unless, of course, there's a service process that has the explicit task of managing the memory consumed by all SQL Express instances, which I've never seen or heard about.

Comment: Begging people to remove downvotes on what is naturally a bad answer is unlikely to get you upvotes, regardless of what source you cite. If you really want to cite source, go load up several instances and show their actual load in memory. That's the only way to know for sure. Either that, or show us the Microsoft code that governs the behavior of SQL Express. It's always per instance management, because each service is self-contained from top to bottom. All the management services work over ports.

Comment: Wow - I had no idea that this would be such a controversial question!  I am actually going to see if I can try it before I vote/resolve.

Comment: `Maximum memory utilized (SQL Server Database Engine)` Notice how they use the same terminology there as they do on the line: `Maximum Compute Capacity Used by a Single Instance (SQL Server Database Engine)1` (for those playing at home, the point of that is that they are the same measurement) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx#CrossBoxScale and I also love how the answer on SO that was linked to is WRONG WRONG WRONG. Start with "1 core or 4 sockets", the editors can't even copy-paste correctly.